# Using a Microsoft access DB .accdb on a linux server with Node.js

Tags: node.js, ms-access

So, I got this working on windows easy, and that is not surprising. But I am more concerned about running this on a production linux server.

Is there a way to get the Access Runtime 2013 to work on a linux based system without throwing some weird way of doing it. If not, then I am going to have to rethink my plans.

Just as a code base this is what I am doing:

```
const ADODB = require('node-adodb');
ADODB.debug = true;
//Bring in LUT Database
const LUTDB = ADODB.open(
  'Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=Database1.accdb;Persist Security Info=False'
);
LUTDB.query('SELECT * FROM Table1')
  .then(data => {
    console.log(data);
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
  });
```

Answer (score 5):

Nope.

The Access Runtime (as well as the database engine and full application) is only compatible with Windows, and barring Wine stuff/other trickery that's not production-worthy, it plain won't work.

There are third-party ODBC/JDBC drivers for Access out there that do work on Linux, but nothing official from Microsoft.

My recommendation would be: either don't use Access on Linux (best), or try UCanAccess with a JDBC wrapper (not affiliated). Note that the accdb file format has changed a number of times, so you can expect trouble/incompatibilities if you don't use an actively maintained product.

Comment: Hmmm, thats what I thought, guess I'll just use my main DB for the things I want. I wanted a LUT Database that it would just be used for read-only stuff but, I guess I can just go with my MongoDB to do that. Thanks though!

Comment: Any thought on how I could use UCanAccess files in node js to connect to a MS Access DB?

Comment: Well, 1. Get a JDBC wrapper for node, 2. Get UCanAccess, 3. Use them together. There are plenty of tutorials for UCanAccess (e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/21955257/7296893) and JDBC wrappers (node-jdbc, node-any-jdbc, etc) come with documentation. If you've made an attempt but failed you can ask about it in a new question.

Comment: Thanks Erik for pointing me to the right path. I did similar things with NodeGyp and OpenCV4NodeJS wrapper for C++ OpenCV, I think I have a good chance to get it done.

Comment: @ErikA I got it to work many thanks. I'm using MacOS Catalina, and UCanAccess work just fine for the basics, didn't check on advanced yet. I'm posting an answer so others can avoid confusions.

Comment: I was able to use it to retrieve Ole Object in Blob Format (that reads Long Binary Data in Access table) and save the Pictures from the blob. The key is to look on UCanAccess Classes API to know which methods (Argument types + quantity (overloads)) are available to use with JDBC package. People with JS-only background will find it a bit challenging though.

Answer (score 2):

Like @ErikA suggests in his answer, if anyone is using Linux or MacOS, you can use BOTH:

1. The open source UCanAccess http://ucanaccess.sourceforge.net/site.html
2. Java library with the JDBC wrappers as package: https://www.npmjs.com/package/jdbc

I'm using MacOS Catalina. You can initialize a project with npm in a new directory:

```
npm init
npm i --save jdbc
mkdir index.js
```

Download and copy the 5 UCanAccess jar files:

- Main jar `ucanaccess-5.0.1.jar`
- All 4 jar files in `lib` directory

They can be put in the same directory too. I created a simple MS Access `.accdb` file with 1 table: `employees (id, name, photo)`

And, in `index.js` file, here is the codes to connect and SELECT to DB (most codes are from JDBC package, with a few modifications marked with `// CUSTOM` over the modified line):

```
var JDBC = require('jdbc');
var jinst = require('jdbc/lib/jinst');

if (!jinst.isJvmCreated()) {
  jinst.addOption("-Xrs");

  // CUSTOM
  jinst.setupClasspath([
    './drivers/ucanaccess-5.0.1.jar',
    './drivers/commons-lang3-3.8.1.jar',
    './drivers/commons-logging-1.2.jar',
    './drivers/hsqldb-2.5.0.jar',
    './drivers/jackcess-3.0.1.jar'
  ]);
}

var config = {
  // Required
  // CUSTOM
  url: 'jdbc:ucanaccess:///Users/Keitel/repos/mjsp/badge/badge-test.accdb',

  // Optional
  // CUSTOM
  drivername: 'net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessDriver',
  minpoolsize: 10,
  maxpoolsize: 100,

  // Note that if you sepecify the user and password as below, they get
  // converted to properties and submitted to getConnection that way.  That
  // means that if your driver doesn't support the 'user' and 'password'
  // properties this will not work.  You will have to supply the appropriate
  // values in the properties object instead.
  // user: 'SA',
  // CUSTOM
  user: '',
  password: '',
  properties: {}
};

var hsqldb = new JDBC(config);

hsqldb.initialize(function(err) {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err);
    // CUSTOM
    return;
  }

  // CUSTOM
  console.log('successfully initialized');
});


// This assumes initialization as above.
// For series execution.
var asyncjs = require('async');

hsqldb.reserve(function(err, connObj) {
  // The connection returned from the pool is an object with two fields
  // {uuid: <uuid>, conn: <Connection>}
  if (connObj) {
    console.log("Using connection: " + connObj.uuid);
    // Grab the Connection for use.
    var conn = connObj.conn;

    // Adjust some connection options.  See connection.js for a full set of
    // supported methods.
    asyncjs.series([
      function(callback) {
        conn.setAutoCommit(false, function(err) {
          if (err) {
            callback(err);
          } else {
            callback(null);
          }
        });
      },
      // CUSTOM
      // Skip Schema selection with MS Access DB
    ], function(err, results) {
      // Check for errors if need be.
      // results is an array.
      if (err) {
        console.log('autocommit error', err);
      }
    });

    // Query the database.
    asyncjs.series([
      function(callback) {
        // Select statement example.
        conn.createStatement(function(err, statement) {
          if (err) {
            callback(err);
          } else {
            // Adjust some statement options before use.  See statement.js for
            // a full listing of supported options.
            statement.setFetchSize(100, function(err) {
              if (err) {
                callback(err);
              } else {
                // CUSTOM
                statement.executeQuery(
                  'SELECT id, name FROM employees;',
                  function(err, resultset) {
                    if (err) {
                      callback(err)
                    } else {
                      resultset.toObjArray(function(err, results) {
                        console.log('results', results);
                        callback(null, resultset);
                      });
                    }
                  }
                );
              }
            });
          }
        });
      },
    ], function(err, results) {
      // Results can also be processed here.
      // Release the connection back to the pool.
      hsqldb.release(connObj, function(err) {
        if (err) {
          console.log(err.message);
        }
      });
    });
  }
});
```

The results came out in terminal as:

```
results [
  { ID: 1, name: 'Keitel Jovin' },
  { ID: 2, name: 'Jetro Joseph' },
  { ID: 3, name: 'Bertha Bazile' }
]
```

Comment: I've learned how to Properly use the UCanAccess and JackAccess Java methods inside this JDBC package, and I retrieve all Pictures from Long Binary Data (OLE Object). HINTS: Get the data from resultset object with : `while(resultset._rs.nextSync()) {`, with `._rs` is the key to go for Java methods call. And Java methods are mapped from UcanAccess API, that extends JackAccess API, so you can use both. I'll put the 2 code API below. If anyone want code example, I'll edit this answer to give example for parsing Pictures out of Blob Ole object.

Comment: UcanAccess: https://jar-download.com/javaDoc/net.sf.ucanaccess/ucanaccess/4.0.3/net/ucanaccess/jdbc/UcanaccessResultSet.html

JackAccess: https://jackcess.sourceforge.io/apidocs/com/healthmarketscience/jackcess/util/OleBlob.html

Comment: And if you get error like method not found or not exist, it might be because Java is OOP, then the methods re recognized along with their Argument Type and Numbers that make them unique (Overload methods). So make sure you're calling them passing the right parameters.